# Firebase creating custom token using spotify signin?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, spotify

I am trying to implement a 'Log in with Spotify' feature for my react app. I am trying to follow [this](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/10/authenticate-your-firebase-users-with.html) blog but I am not able use

```
firebase.auth().createCustomToken(uid)
```

as i get the error

> .createCustomToken is not a function

I also tried using firebase-admin package but I run into

> Can't resolve util in /node_modules/@google_cloud/common/build/src

This is what I have tried to do so far. I have never used firebase before. Any help would be appreciated.

> 

```
 import {getAuth} from 'firebase-admin/auth';
 import { initializeApp } from 'firebase-admin/app';
 import admin from 'firebase-admin';

var serviceAccount = require('./service-account.json')
const spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi();
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
})
let uid= 5;

getAuth().createCustomToken(uid).then(function(customToken) {
  console.log(customToken);
});
```

Comment: Can you share your complete code so we can also see how you are importing these functions? And also your `firebase-admin` version ?

Comment: Updated the post. I tried to use firebase-admin in the same file but from what I read, it should be on the server side right? Have no idea how to use that when I am getting the spotify access token here.

Comment: You are using `getAuth()` from Firebase client SDK and that does not have `createCustomToken()` method. Have you tried `import { getAuth } from "firebase-admin/auth"` ? You also need to `import { initializeApp } from 'firebase-admin/app'
` and initialize the Admin SDK. You can just remove client SDK from here `"firebase/*"` imports

Comment: Did that but there's still the 'util' error. I'll update the code now so you see what exactly it is I am doing currently. Error in console: " Cannot find module 'fs'"

Comment: To initialize Admin SDK, you'll need a service account (or [ADC](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production)). The firebaseConfig is for client SDK. Can you try initializing the Admin SDK with a service account as in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize-sdk).

Comment: Updated the code which now uses service account. The util and fs errors remain

Comment: Are you trying to use Firebase Admin SDK in a client web app (React/Vue) by chance? It's supposed to be used on server side only. You generate the custom token on server side (cloud  function or so) and send it back to client and then use `signInWithCustomToken()`

Comment: Yeah thats probably why firebase-admin doesn't work. I was trying to get the spotify accesstoken post authorization and then attempting to create firebase token on the same file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blog post you're following is a few years old, and recent versions of the Firebase SDK for JavaScript have switched to a different syntax (to allow build tools to automatically exclude unused parts of the SDK from you app bundle).

What used to be:

```
firebase.auth().createCustomToken(uid)...
```

Is now accomplished with:

```
createCustomToken(getAuth(), uid)...
```

For more on this, I recommend also checking out the [upgrade guide for the new v9 SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade).

---

Update: as Dharmaraj [commented below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71515689/firebase-creating-custom-token-using-spotify-signin/71515809#comment126400797_71515809) `createCustomToken` is still a method on the auth object.

Comment: I might have missed any recent update but [`createCustomToken`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.auth.baseauth.md#baseauthcreatecustomtoken) still seems to be a method on Firebase Admin's auth instance and not a function exported from the auth SDK.

Comment: Yeah I still cannot use createCustomToken here

Comment: Ah... thanks Dharmaraj.   I thought all former methods were now top-level functions in the modular Admin SDKs too.